# Comparing two string arrays, my console application "stops responding"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am attempting to compare 2 string arrays and I cannot seem to figure out the problem. The goal is to put them in alphabetical order. I attempted to use bubble sort but I cant get it to work. Not sure if it matters or not but the arrays are being read in from a file and the last names are being compared, and I want this function to rearrange them into alphabetical order. Thank you

```
    sortInput(accountData);


    void sortInput(string theAccounts[5][7])
{
    bool swap;
    string temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;
        int row = 7;
        for (int count = 0; count < (row - 1); count++)
        {
            if (strcmp(theAccounts[count][2], theAccounts[count + 1][2]) < 0)
            {
                temp = theAccounts[count][2];
                theAccounts[count][2] = theAccounts[count + 1][2];
                theAccounts[count + 1][2] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

Here is the .txt file they are being read in from:

```
bham@gnet.com       Blake       Ham         squid62     1987    U   Teacher
jdark@att.net       Jim         Dark        gymrat32    1985    A   Master
hgreen@lakes.net    Hannah      Green       flower22    2007    U   Apprentice
tsmith@dna.com      Tom         Smith       tuna20      2000    U   Teacher
jarrow@pnet.com     James       Arrow       ahoy10      2005    U   Apprentice
```

Comment: *I attempted to use bubble sort* -- Why? Is there a reason you're not using `std::sort`?

Comment: are you using std::string?

Comment: If the input really is `theAccounts[5][7]` you cannot use `row = 7;` as the limit for the first index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your bubble sort, then you should set `int row = 5;` not `7`. And if you are going to swap whole row, you need to swap all elements in row not just key ordered by 2nd index:

```
const int COLUMNS_COUNT = 7;
//...
if (strcmp(theAccounts[count][2], theAccounts[count + 1][2]) < 0)
{
    //Swap whole row
    for ( int j = 0; j < COLUMNS_COUNT - 1; j++ )
    {
        temp = theAccounts[count][j];
        theAccounts[count][j] = theAccounts[count + 1][j+1];
        theAccounts[count + 1][j+1] = temp;     
    }
    swap = true;
}
```

Or just you can choose another way and solve this task with STL:

Try to use other container, think about `std::map` it is made specially to keep elements sorted when you insert them and hold additional field for value, sou we get here key=>value container. Your algorithm is strange `strcmp(theAccounts[count][2], theAccounts[count + 1][2]` it compares only `2` index per row. So I guess you want to sort order by one of the columns from given input text, Choose column data and pass in as first parameter to `std::pair` like here `map1.insert(std::make_pair("Ham", "bham@gnet.com       Blake       Ham         squid62     1987    U   Teacher"));`. Then you will have sort order by third field from your input data.

My example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    //Input maps test data
    std::map<std::string,std::string> map1;
    map1.insert(std::make_pair("Ham", "bham@gnet.com       Blake       Ham         squid62     1987    U   Teacher"));
    map1.insert(std::make_pair("Dark", "jdark@att.net       Jim         Dark        gymrat32    1985    A   Master"));
    map1.insert(std::make_pair("Green", "hgreen@lakes.net    Hannah      Green       flower22    2007    U   Apprentice"));
    map1.insert(std::make_pair("Smith", "tsmith@dna.com      Tom         Smith       tuna20      2000    U   Teacher"));
    map1.insert(std::make_pair("Arrow", "jarrow@pnet.com     James       Arrow       ahoy10      2005    U   Apprentice"));


    //Trace set's order as they are saved in container
    std::cout << "Map1:" << std::endl;

    std::for_each(map1.begin(), map1.end(), []( const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& el )
        {
            std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << std::endl;
        } );

    return 0;
}
```

Result is:

```
Map1:
Arrow: jarrow@pnet.com     James       Arrow       ahoy10      2005    U   Apprentice
Dark: jdark@att.net       Jim         Dark        gymrat32    1985    A   Master
Green: hgreen@lakes.net    Hannah      Green       flower22    2007    U   Apprentice
Ham: bham@gnet.com       Blake       Ham         squid62     1987    U   Teacher
Smith: tsmith@dna.com      Tom         Smith       tuna20      2000    U   Teacher
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

So you don't have to worry about sorting data, just use `std::map` container. If you want to use specific compare algorithm, use third parameter to pass compare function:

```
auto MapWithSpecificCmp = std::map<std::string, std::string, std::function<bool(const std::string&, const std::string&)>>{
        [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
        {
            //Specific compare
            return a < b;
        }
    };
```